# Why is a destructuring augmented assignment not possible?

Tags: python, destructuring, augmented-assignment

Destructuring is possible in python:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

Augmented assignment is also possible:

```
b += 1
```

But is there a reason destructuring augmented assignment cannot be done?:

```
a, b += 1, 2
> SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

From what I can tell, destructuring is a language thing; it cannot be modified by something like `object.__add__()`. Why won't the language call `object.__iadd__()` on each part of the augmented assignment separately?

Comment: Personally, when I look at `a, b += 1, 2`, I'm not sure what it should do. `(a, b) + (1, 2)` equals `(1, 2, 1, 2)` so I would expect `(a, b) +=  (1, 2)` to be  the same as `(a, b) = (a, b) + (1, 2)`, which equals `(a, b) = (1, 2, 1, 2)` but how do you unpack that?

Comment: Perhaps it's because the base expression `a,b = a,b + 1,2` is invalid.

Comment: These comments make sense, thank you. I guess then my question is, why is the augmented rule applied before the destructuring rule. `a, b += 1, 2 => a = a + 1; b = b + 2` And maybe the answer is, it might be confusing.

Comment: It's unclear for me, how the expressions like the `a, b += 1, a` could be evaluated, if such a syntax is allowed. Should we evaluate `a += 1` first and get an `a'`, than `b += a'`, or just evaluate `a += 1`, `b += a`? Looks like it's an undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think that @MikhailStepanov has found a good answer as to why this wouldn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's because of undefined behaviour in expressions like a:

```
a, b += 1, a
```

How it should be evaluated? Like this

```
a' = a + 1
b = b + a'
```

or just

```
b = b + a
a = a + 1
```

- it's unclear. So, destructuring augmented assignment is not allowed.